# Programmatically read a password from an Elytron BCFIPS credential store

Tags: java, elytron

I created a FIPS 140-2 Compliant Credential Store using the Bouncy Castle provider. As it is described in the documentation, first I created the secter key:

keytool -genseckey -alias key -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -keystore keystore.bcfks -storetype BCFKS -storepass myPass -keypass myPass

Then I created the crefential store like:

/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=myCredentialstore:add(relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir, credential-reference={clear-text=”${ENC::myResolver:myEncodedExpression}”}, implementation-properties={keyAlias=key, external=true, externalPath=credentialStore.bcfks, keyStoreType=BCFKS}, create=true, path=keystore.bcfks, modifiable=true)

The credential store works fine, but now I need to read a password from it programmatically. I found and tried two ways doing this.

Solution 1.

```
public static Password getpassword() throws CredentialStoreException {
    Password storePassword = ClearPassword.createRaw(ClearPassword.ALGORITHM_CLEAR,
                                                     MY_CLEAR_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    ProtectionParameter protectionParameter = new CredentialSourceProtectionParameter(IdentityCredentials.NONE.withCredential(new PasswordCredential(storePassword)));

    Provider bcProvider = new BouncyCastleFipsProvider();
    Security.addProvider(bcProvider);

    KeyStoreCredentialStore keyStoreCredentialStore = new KeyStoreCredentialStore();

    Map<String, String> kscsConfiguration = new HashMap<>();
    String keystorePath = "myPath/keystore.bcfks";
    String externalPath = "myPath/credentialStore.bcfks";

    kscsConfiguration.put("location", keystorePath);
    kscsConfiguration.put("modifiable", "true");
    kscsConfiguration.put("keyStoreType", "BCFKS");
    kscsConfiguration.put("keyAlias", "key");
    kscsConfiguration.put("external", "true");
    kscsConfiguration.put("externalPath", externalPath);

    Provider[] providers = { bcProvider };
    keyStoreCredentialStore.initialize(kscsConfiguration, protectionParameter, providers);

    PasswordCredential passwordVredential = keyStoreCredentialStore.retrieve(WEBUSER_PASSWORD_ALIAS,
                                                                             PasswordCredential.class,
                                                                             KeyStoreCredentialStore.KEY_STORE_CREDENTIAL_STORE,
                                                                             null,
                                                                             protectionParameter);
    return passwordVredential.getPassword();
}
```

With this code I can read the aliases from the credential store, but I'm nor able to retrieve the password. I just can't figure out how to put the proper parameters into the retrieve() function call.

Solution 2.

I tried to use the SeviceContainer, but the call CurrentServiceContainer.getServiceContainer() returns null.

public static String getClientSecret(String credentialStore, String secretAlias) {
final ServiceName SERVICE_NAME_CRED_STORE = ServiceName.of("org", "wildfly", "security", "credential-store");
final ServiceName sn = ServiceName.of(SERVICE_NAME_CRED_STORE, credentialStore);
final ServiceRegistry registry = CurrentServiceContainer.getServiceContainer();
final ServiceController<?> credStoreService = registry.getService(sn);
final CredentialStore cs = (CredentialStore) credStoreService.getValue();
if (!cs.exists(secretAlias, PasswordCredential.class)) {
throw new CredentialStoreException("Alias " + secretAlias + " not found in credential store.");
}
final Password password;
try {
password = cs.retrieve(secretAlias, PasswordCredential.class).getPassword();
} catch (CredentialStoreException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
if (!(password instanceof ClearPassword)) {
throw new ClassCastException("Password is not of type ClearPassword");
}
return new String(((ClearPassword) password).getPassword());
}

How could I retrieve the password from that credential sore?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to obtain and use an encrypted expression that was created in the server's management model apart from the management model itself.

You can try to look at the credential store APIs in the [encryption module of elytron](https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/1.x/encryption/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/encryption/CipherUtil.java#L44) if you can use those.